# How I can I specify "page number" when webscraping dynamic HTML using Python's requests.post function?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to learn how to scrape webpages with dynamic HTML using `requests` library in Python.  I've been able  to get the HTML but I can't figure out how to actually get the data for different pages.  If you notice on the bottom of the image there are page numbers:

1. How can I specify page number with `requests.post`
2. How can I know how many pages are available? Would it be as easy as a page range and then `try` and `except`?
3. How can I know which arguments could be used for my `data` dictionary in `requests.post`?

[image]

Here's how I access the requests:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://search.aap.org/nicu/', 
data = {'SearchCriteria.Level':'1', 'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}) #key:value
print(r.text)
```

Here's the output:

https://pastebin.com/raw/HMBZWR36

Here's the part where it says the page number:

```
# <div id="myPager">
#     <div class="pagination-container"><ul class="pagination blue-pager"><li class="blue-pager active"><span>1</span></li></ul></div>

# </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on that page is loaded dynamically using javascript so you can't just get it with requests from that page. Working with the Developer tag in the browser, you can intercept the xhr generating the data and use that with requests. That's what it looks like in this case.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://search.aap.org/nicu/',
}

params = (
    ('Model', 'X.PagedList.StaticPagedList`1[AAP.Website.Search.NICU.Web.ViewModels.NicuVm]'),
    ('jsonSearchVmString', '{"SearchCriteria":{"Name":null,"City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"Level":2,"LevelAssigner":null,"BedNumberRange":0},"States":null,"Levels":null,"LevelAssigners":null,"BedNumberRangeList":null,"NumberOfPages":0}'),
    ('page', '2'),
    ('class', 'blue-pager'),
    ('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'),
    ('_', '1603318486561'),
)

response = requests.get('https://search.aap.org/nicu/', headers=headers, params=params)
```

One of the parameters is `('page', '2')`; if you wrap your request in a `for` loop in the appropriate range, you should be able to do `requests.get()` on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use POST request in this case. If look at the URL when you click on next page, you will see all parameters that you can change. Also, to get all pages you can parse the HTML and look for `<a rel="next">` tag. If the tag doesn't exists, you're on the last page (try to change the `"LevelAssigner"` parameter from `3` to other value):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://search.aap.org/nicu/?Model=X.PagedList.StaticPagedList`1[AAP.Website.Search.NICU.Web.ViewModels.NicuVm]&jsonSearchVmString={"SearchCriteria":{"Name":null,"City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"Level":0,"LevelAssigner":"3","BedNumberRange":0},"States":null,"Levels":null,"LevelAssigners":null,"BedNumberRangeList":null,"NumberOfPages":0}&class=blue-pager&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&page='

page = 1
while True:
    print('Page {}..'.format(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url + str(page)).content, 'html.parser')

    for row in soup.select('.row.font-700'):
        print(row.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))

    next_page = soup.select_one('a[rel="next"]')
    if not next_page:
        break

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
Page 1..
ANDERSON REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER Meridian, MS 39301
Ann & Robert H. Lurie Children's Hospital of Chicago Chicago, IL 60611
BAYSTATE MEDICAL CENTER Springfield, MA 01199
Beacon Children's Hospital South Bend, IN 46601-1033
BEN TAUB GENERAL HOSPITAL Houston, TX 77030
Page 2..
BETH ISRAEL DEACONESS MEDICAL CENTER Boston, MA 02215
BRIGHAM AND WOMEN'S HOSPITAL Boston, MA 02115
CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL OF NEW ORLEANS New Orleans, LA 70118
CLEVELAND CLINIC formally MERIDIA HILLCREST HOSPITAL Mayfield Heights, OH 44124
EAST JEFFERSON GENERAL HOSPITAL Metairie, LA 70006
Page 3..
GEORGETOWN UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL Washington, DC 20007
GREENWICH HOSPITAL Greenwich, CT 06830
HELEN DEVOS CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL Grand Rapids, MI 49503
INOVA LOUDOUN HOSPITAL Leesburg, VA 20176
JACOBI MEDICAL CENTER Bronx, NY 10461
Page 4..
LAKEVIEW REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER HOSPITAL Covington, LA 70433
LOYOLA UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER Maywood, IL 60153
MELROSE WAKEFIELD HOSPITAL Melrose, MA 02176
MERCYHEALTH HOSPITAL ROCKTON AVENUE CAMPUS formally ROCKFORD HEALTH SYSTEM Rockford, IL 61103
RUSH FOUNDATION HOSPITAL Meridian, MS 39301
Page 5..
Shetal Shah Valhalla, NY 10595
SLIDELL MEMORIAL HOSPITAL Slidell, LA 70458
SOUTHERN NEW HAMPSHIRE MEDICAL CENTER Nashua, NH 03061
St Mary Medical Center Apple Valley, CA 92307
ST. AGNES HOSPITAL Baltimore, MD 21229
Page 6..
THE CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL AT NAVICENT HEALTH Macon, GA 31208-6000
TOURO INFIRMARY New Orleans, LA 70115
TULANE LAKESIDE HOSPITAL Metairie, LA 70001
UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER -  SUNY STONY BROOK Stony Brook, NY 11794-8111
UNIVERSITY OF IOWA CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL Iowa City, IA 52242
Page 7..
UNIVERSITY OF LOUISVILLE SCHOOL OF MEDICINE Louisville, KY 40232-5070
UNIVERSITY OF MISSISSIPPI MEDICAL CENTER Jackson, MS 39216-4505
UNIVERSITY OF ROCHESTER MEDICAL CENTER Rochester, NY 14642
UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTON MEDICAL CENTER Seattle, WA 98195
WakeMed Cary Hospital Cary, NC 27518
Page 8..
WakeMed North Family Health & Women’s Hospital Raleigh, NC 27614
WakeMed Raleigh Hospital Raleigh, NC 27610
Wellstar Kennestone Hospital NICU Marietta, GA 30066
WILLIS KNIGHTON CENTER FOR WOMEN'S HEALTH Shreveport, LA 71118
WOMAN'S HOSPITAL Baton Rouge, LA 70817
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is starting to make sense.  Just so I can understand how to adjust the parameters so I can scrape through all of the pages, I have a few question: 1) `"Level":0,"LevelAssigner":"3","BedNumberRange":0`  Why did you set these values?  2) There are plural fields (e.g. Levels, LevelAssigners, BedNumberRangeList) outside of the SearchCriteria.  How do you know which ones to adjust? 3) Why is "NumberOfPages":0? Cheers

Comment: @O.rka I didn't set the values by myself. I copied the url when I clicked to, for example, on page 2 in the pagination bar. The values are set by the list boxes found on the page.